# 1999 T&C Low-beam Headlight Replacement

Tags: headlight, chrysler, town-and-country

My question is very basic. How do you replace a low-beam headlight on a '99 Chrysler Town&Country Lxi? Also can I replace just high-beams with blue lights?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It's best to ask a single question in a single posting; life gets confusing when you ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you replace a low-beam headlight on a '99 Chrysler Town&Country Lxi?

If you open your hood and look directly behind where the headlight bulb is located, you'll see some wire protruding out from the area. Pull this plug out from the back of the headlight bulb, then turn the retainer ring counter-clockwise to remove it, then pull the bulb out. When replacing with a new bulb **DO NOT TOUCH THE BULB WITH YOUR BARE HANDS!** This is very important as oils from your fingers will damage the bulb and reduce the life expectancy to less than two weeks. Use a pair of nitrile gloves or handle it with a paper towel. Replace the bulb in the same manner as you pulled the old one out.

> Also can I replace just high-beams with blue lights?

No you cannot since your system is a two bulb system (one bulb per side). If it were a four bulb system you could do this for the bulb which is used on the high beam side.

[This video for a Dodge Caravan](https://youtu.be/KAen_4Jg6BA) may be of use to you.